# center a cross png into a css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am doing a Tic Tac Toe in a web page.

Everything is working and now I want to replace text inside cells by images of circle or cross. Each div contains an image that I show or not depending on the user's input. That's why I want to insert and center every img elements. How can I display these cross.png inside every cell ? For now, the cross image is in the middle of the page

```css
  .grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  .grid-container>div {
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #button1 {
    background-color: #4caf50;
    /* Green */
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  #button2 {
    background-color: #614caf;
    /* Green */
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  #button3 {
    background-color: #d36544;
    /* Green */
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    font-size: 16px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div id="0">
    <img id="img0" , src="images/cross.png" />
  </div>

  <div id="1">
    <img id="img1" , src="images/cross.png" />
  </div>

  <div id="2">
    <img id="img2" , src="images/cross.png" />
  </div>

  <div id="3">
    <img id="img3" , src="images/cross.png" />
  </div>

  <div id="4">
    <img id="img4" , src="images/cross.png" />
  </div>

  <div id="5">
    <img id="img5" , src="images/cross.png" />
  </div>

  <div id="6">
    <img id="img6" , src="images/cross.png" />
  </div>

  <div id="7">
    <img id="img7" , src="images/cross.png" />
  </div>

  <div id="8">
    <img id="img8" , src="images/cross.png" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="choice-container">
  <button id="button1">Cross</button>
  <button id="button2">Circle</button>
  <button id="button3">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS seems fine if we add the missing closing brace to the first rule block. We'll also remove the commas from the HTML.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background-color: black;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#button1 {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  /* Green */
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  font-size: 16px;
}

#button2 {
  background-color: #614caf;
  /* Green */
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  font-size: 16px;
}

#button3 {
  background-color: #d36544;
  /* Green */
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div id="0">
    <img id="img0" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40" />
  </div>

  <div id="1">
    <img id="img1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40" />
  </div>

  <div id="2">
    <img id="img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40" />
  </div>

  <div id="3">
    <img id="img3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40" />
  </div>

  <div id="4">
    <img id="img4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40" />
  </div>

  <div id="5">
    <img id="img5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40" />
  </div>

  <div id="6">
    <img id="img6" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40" />
  </div>

  <div id="7">
    <img id="img7" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40" />
  </div>

  <div id="8">
    <img id="img8" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="choice-container">
  <button id="button1">Cross</button>
  <button id="button2">Circle</button>
  <button id="button3">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Other tips:

- Use classes for your CSS instead of IDs. This makes them reusable.
- Combine all the repeat CSS rules into a class, and apply it to all the buttons. Alternatively, wrap the buttons in a container and use a class on it to target the buttons, as `.container button {}`.
- Add `body` tags around your content (missing in the unedited original post)

Answer (score 1):

Only one character is missing. At the end of the first class definition: `}`

```
.grid-container {
  ...
} <--- this one
```